# How to access the setup wizard on Sonicwall TZ 100 firewall

Tags: networking, local-area-network, sonicwall

I am trying to setup a TZ 100 firewall. I am following [these instructions](http://apetec.com/support/TZ200-Setup.htm) and I have attempted to follow these instructions:

"Connect your computer to the LAN (X0) port on the SonicWALL. Connect an ethernet cable from the WAN (X1) port on the SonicWALL to the LAN port on your internet router or modem."

So currently, I have X0 going to my computer and X1 going a LAN port on my router. I also tried connecting to my modem. However, after then trying to load the configuration page, 192.168.168.168, it will not load nor will it ping.

I have tried the manual reset button (currently, there is an indicator light with a wrench blinking on the firewall) as well. I have also tried pinging 192.168.168.168 to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

I have also referred to the getting started guide, which so far, doesn't have much information beyond the linked page. I have ensured DHCP addressing is configured on my computer as it suggests.

Comment: Have you verified that your computer has an ip address in the 192.168.168.x subnet?